# RxJava and Multi-threaded Variables

Tags: multithreading, scope, rx-java, rx-java2, race-condition

The code below is only for demonstration purposes. This is not development code, so please no criticisms about "bad practice". It's only there to convey concepts.

Say you are inside a method, with a null list.

```
public void myMethod() {
  List<Strings> myList = new ArrayList<>(); 
}
```

Right below the myList definition, a multithreaded asynchronous RX Call is made, with a made up callback to return results. Let's sub on **Schedulers.io()**, and observe on **AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()**.

```
getMyStuff.subOn(Schedulers.io()).obsOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Callback(){
      @Override
      public void onDone(List<String> list){
          myList.addAll(list);
      }
})
```

If we place a temporarily block below that, and try to access myList, it will be **null.**

```
Thread.wait(5000);

Assert.true(myList.size() > 0) --> False
```

However, if we do the same, but access it from the **main** thread, it will work.

```
Thread.wait(5000);

RunOnMainThread { //--> This can be done any number of ways.
  Assert.true(myList.size() > 0) --> True
}
```

The entire *working* code would look like

```
public void myMethod() {
  List<Strings> myList = new ArrayList<>();

  getMyStuff.subOn(Schedulers.io()).obsOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).sub(new Callback(){
      @Override
      public void onDone(List<String> list){
          myList.addAll(list);
      }
   })

  Thread.wait(5000);

  RunOnMainThread { //--> This can be done any number of ways.
     Assert.true(myList.size() > 0) --> True
  }
}
```

I've witnessed something similar to this happening in other cases, but I'm stumbled as to why. Is it because every thread has its own stack/region of memory?

Comment: Interesting! So if this was a class variable, would using "volatile" fix this?

Comment: This spiked a question from my side. Isn't this all luck? The main thread is a looper thread, meaning it might not execute immediately, right? isn't it just by coincidence that once the work gets run the list is initialized? Thanks

Comment: This is because you update `myList` on the main thread and then schedule the size check on the main thread after some delay.

Comment: This is easily reproducible if you follow those steps. The "only for demo purposes" was there so people wouldn't complain about bad practices, thinking I'm using timers to handle asynchronous behaviour.

Comment: Wait, there's a `List<Strings> myList = null` but there's no `list = new ArrayList<>()` or equivalent... I understand it's just a demo, but still..

Comment: Fixed :D.......

Comment: The right way to access to myList is inside of onDone, then u don't need use Thread.wait

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised that you don't get a compiler warning that myList is out of scope. It should be declared as static or moved to the Class scope. Since the call to sub is asynchronous, the response will arrive on another thread that is out of myMethod's scope.